# tkinter gui for loading any CSV and displaying columns in gui ( apply filters, sort , hide/unhide)

Tags: pandas, tkinter

I have semi functional working-script.

1. I have a "restore original" button that is supposed to unhide all-columns by using the original dataframe and displaying that in treeview.  This somehow does not work.  Whenever I hide a column, I cannot do "restore original" and bring the original display back.
2. Everytime, I do any operation like "apply filter" or "apply sort",
   all the columns shrink and they become tiny. I then have to manually expand each column to make it readable.
3. I am trying to make each column show up in different font-color(foreground). Somehow the self.tree.insert doesn't seem to honor a list/tuple of tags as an input to the row.
4. copy_to_clipboard / show_full_string seem to have errors and they don't work.

- **SCRIPT**

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, simpledialog, messagebox
  import pandas as pd


  class CSVViewerApp:
      def __init__(self, root, csv_file,delimiter):
          self.root = root
          self.root.title("CSV Viewer")
          self.root.geometry("1200x600")

          self.df = pd.DataFrame()  # Initial empty DataFrame
          self.filtered_df = None  # DataFrame to store filtered data
          self.column_widths = defaultdict(dict)  # Dictionary to store column widths

          self.tree_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
          self.tree_frame.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)


          self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tree_frame, show="headings", selectmode="browse")
          self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

          self.tree_scroll_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tree_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
          self.tree_scroll_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tree_frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)

          self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.tree_scroll_y.set, xscrollcommand=self.tree_scroll_x.set)

          self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
          self.tree_scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
          self.tree_scroll_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

          self.tree_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          self.tree_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

          self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

          ##### BUTTONS ######
          load_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Load CSV", command=self.load_csv)
          load_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

          self.filter_button = tk.Button(root, text="Apply Filter", command=self.apply_filter)
          self.filter_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=5)

          self.sort_button = tk.Button(root, text="Apply Sort", command=self.sort_column)
          self.sort_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=5)

          self.hide_button = tk.Button(root, text="Hide Column", command=self.hide_column)
          self.hide_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=5)

          self.restore_original_button = tk.Button(root, text="restore original", command=self.restore_original)
          self.restore_original_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=5)

          save_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Save", command=self.save_to_csv)
          save_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

          #### EVENT BINDINGS ######
          self.tree.bind("<Button-1>", self.copy_to_clipboard)
          self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.show_full_string)


          self.df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,sep=delimiter)
          self.orig_df = self.df
          # Display the loaded data
          try:
              self.display_data(self.df)
          except Exception as e:
              messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error loading CSV file: {str(e)}")


      def load_csv(self):
          file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select CSV File", filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv*")])

          if file_path:
              # Ask the user for the delimiter
              delimiter = simpledialog.askstring("Delimiter", "Enter CSV delimiter (default is comma):", initialvalue=",")

              if delimiter is None:
                  # User clicked Cancel
                  delimiter = ","

              # Use the specified delimiter when reading the CSV
              self.orig_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=delimiter)
              self.latest_df = self.orig_df.copy()
              self.display_data(self.latest_df)

      def save_to_csv(self):
          # Implement save to CSV logic
          #file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".csv.gz", filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv*")])
          file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".csv.gz")

          if file_path:
              self.latest_df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

      def get_column_width(self, column):
          max_length = max(
              self.latest_df[column].astype(str).apply(len).max(),
              len(column)
          )
          width = min(150, max_length) + 10
          self.column_widths[column] = width
          return width  # Add padding for aesthetics

      def display_data(self,df):
          # Clear existing data
          for child in self.tree.get_children():
              self.tree.delete(child)

          # Display index and column headers
          self.tree["columns"] = tuple(df.columns)
          self.latest_df = df

          # Set styles for columns
          styles = []
          for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
              color = self.get_color(i)
              styles.append(f"col_{i}")
              # Determine the maximum width needed for the column           
              max_width = self.get_column_width(col)
              # Set the column width based on the maximum width
              self.tree.column(col, width=max_width)            
              self.tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.W)
              self.tree.tag_configure(f"col_{i}", foreground=color)
              #self.tree.tag_configure(col, foreground=color)
              print(f"Tag: col_{i} , Color: {color}")

          for i, row in df.iterrows():
              row_values = []
              tags = tuple(f"col_{j}" for j in range(len(df.columns)))
              print("-I- row= {} {} tags => {}".format(i,row,tags))
              for col in df.columns:
                  value = str(row[col])
                  row_values.append(value)

              self.tree.insert("", "end", values=row_values, tags=tags)

          for col in df.columns:
              max_width = self.get_column_width(col)
              self.tree.column(col, width=max_width)
              # Store width for later use
              self.column_widths[col] = max_width




      def get_color(self, index):
          colors = ["red", "brown", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple"]
          return colors[index % len(colors)]


      def apply_filter(self):       
          # Ask user for filter condition and value
          #self.latest_df["children"].str.match('^pd_atc.*$')
          filter_condition = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Filter", "Enter complex filter condition,col, value  (e.g. self.latest_df \[\"children\"\].str.match\('^pd_atc.*$'\)")

          try:
              # Apply filter based on user inputs
              filter_expr = eval(filter_condition)

              #filter_expr = f"self.df['{column_name}'] {filter_condition} {filter_value}"
              filtered_df = self.latest_df.loc[filter_expr]
              self.display_data(filtered_df)
          except Exception as e:
              tk.messagebox.showerror("Filter Error", f"Error applying filter: {str(e)}")

          # Restore widths
          for col in self.column_widths:
              self.tree.column(col, width=self.column_widths[col])


      def hide_column(self):
          column = simpledialog.askstring("Hide Column", "Enter column name:")
          hide_df = self.latest_df

          if column and (column in hide_df.columns):
              # Store the column widths before hiding
              column_widths = {col: self.tree.column(col, option="width") for col in hide_df.columns}

              del hide_df[column]
              self.display_data(hide_df)

              # Restore the column widths after hiding             
              for col in self.column_widths:
                  self.tree.column(col, width=self.column_widths[col])


      def restore_original(self):
          self.latest_df = self.orig_df
          self.display_data(self.latest_df)

          #Reset all column widths to their original size
           # Restore widths
          for col in self.column_widths:
              self.tree.column(col, width=self.column_widths[col])




      def sort_column(self):
          # Ask user for column name
          sort_column = simpledialog.askstring("Sort by Column", "Enter column name:")
          if sort_column is not None and sort_column in self.df.columns:
              # Ask user for sort order
              sort_order_str = simpledialog.askstring("Sort Order", "Enter sort order (True for Ascending, False for Descending):")

          if sort_order_str is not None:
              try:
                  # Convert user input to a boolean
                  sort_order = eval(sort_order_str.capitalize())
              except Exception as e:
                  tk.messagebox.showwarning("Invalid Input", "Invalid sort order. Using default order (Ascending).")
                  sort_order = True
          else:
              # User cancelled the input dialog, use default order
              sort_order = True


          # Sort the DataFrame
          sorted_df = self.latest_df.sort_values(by=sort_column, ascending=sort_order)
          # Display the sorted data
          self.display_data(sorted_df)

           # Restore widths
          for col in self.column_widths:
              self.tree.column(col, width=self.column_widths[col])


      def copy_to_clipboard(self, event):
          item = self.tree.selection()[0]
          values = self.tree.item(item, "values")
          self.root.clipboard_clear()
          self.root.clipboard_append("\t".join(values))
          self.root.update()


      def show_full_string(self, event):
          # Get the row and column under the mouse cursor
          item = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
          col = self.tree.identify_column(event.x)

          if item and col:
              row_index = int(item.split('_')[-1])  # Extract the row index
              col_id = col.split('#')[-1]  # Extract the column ID

              # Get the full string value
              full_string = str(self.latest_df.at[row_index, col_id])

              # Create and configure the pop-up window
              popup = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
              popup.title("Full String")

              label = tk.Label(popup, text=full_string, wraplength=500, justify=tk.LEFT)
              label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
              # Adjust the wraplength and other parameters based on your preference


  def MAIN():
      # Create an ArgumentParser object
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="CSV Viewer Application")

      # Add an argument for the CSV file
      parser.add_argument("csv_file", help="Path to the CSV file")
      parser.add_argument('-delimiter', type=str, default=',', help="This is the delimiter for the file") 

      # Parse the command-line arguments
      args = parser.parse_args()

      # Create the Tkinter root window
      root = tk.Tk()

      # Create an instance of the CSVViewerApp class with the specified CSV file
      app = CSVViewerApp(root, args.csv_file,args.delimiter)

      # Start the Tkinter event loop
      root.mainloop()

  # CALLING MAIN
  MAIN()
  ```